# Leaky epoxied sink drain

Tags: leak, drain, sink

The sink drain pipe was changed to ABS (previously metal), but it leaks at the point where it joins the drain in the wall.

Teflon tape was added on the ABS pipe where the washer contacts it (and possibly on the wall drain pipe threads, but I'm not sure). Then some kind of epoxy was applied on the the wall drain pipe and over the nut. It still leaks (badly).

How to fix this mess?

**EDIT:**
I chiseled off the epoxy and removed the ABS pipe. Now it's clear the nipple, if that's what it is, is severely corroded (see image below) and is most likely the cause of the leak.

How do I remove the nipple, which is really solidly stuck and seems like it will easily get crushed? A Youtube video suggested carefully cutting a tab into the top of the nipple and squeezing it into an oval shape to "easily" unscrew and remove it. Recommended?

Also, assuming I get the nipple out... what should I replace it with? Another galvanized steel nipple or something else?

Epoxied drain pipe:
[image: Top view]

Exposed corroded nipple:
[image: Corroded nipple]

Comment: Nipple removal video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuKHMyyRu9k

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably know what you need to do... remove ALL that crap. Sloppy glues and putties *never* work with plumbing. It needs to be repaired the proper way.

The application of that epoxy has complicated this job. Your mission is to remove all the epoxy so you can see what you are dealing with.

The typical connection at that point: the plastic tube slides into a threaded 1 1/2" galvanized steel nipple (nipple is term for short pipe threaded both ends). A 1/1/2" slip-joint nut and washer on the plastic tube thread to the pipe to effect a seal.

There is a chance that:

- the epoxy cannot be removed without complete destruction of all parts, this would require replacing everything
- you can get the fittings apart only to find that the threads on the 1 1/2" nipple are damaged, this requires nipple replacement.
- the galvanized nipple is so corroded it falls apart in your hands, leaving the threaded part in the wall; replace nipple after special operation to remove broken part still in the wall.

All the scenarios above (and many other things that could go wrong) can be remedied using special tool/procedures/parts/tricks. Taking pictures and bringing parts/pieces to **a good plumbing shop** will help tremendously. IMO you should not even waste your time at the big-box stores.

.

Comment: How would I remove the epoxy? It feels pretty hard... And now that you mention it, I think the nipple's threads were worn/rusty and the nut was very shallow (not much threading). That might have been the reason for the leak, and the motivation for the putty/epoxy as a stop-gap measure.

Comment: If you applied the epoxy to try to fix the leak then it's time to call a plumber or friend who knows how to fix plumbing the correct way. Trying to fix something you know nothing about is not a good way to fix anything.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it The information you provided helped me get started. Suggestions on how to remove the nipple and what to replace it with? I updated my original post.